# How to use in-app-purchasing-1.0.3 in android app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

my android application i want to add the functionality the user to buy book from amazon.

For that follow the https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/documentation/quick-start.html and all step are implement in my app.

I am get error on this code PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest("DeveloperSKU-1234");
This my second project in android so i am not understand how to use and what code.

What's the best way to implement  (additional content or services) in-app purchases in Android ?

i couldn't find any information what i should use. Thanks in advance any help will be very helpful.